# Candidates are randomly highlighted when they reply on the election page

Tags: bug, election

Right now, it seems that some candidates are highlighted (like a question asker is highlighted when he comments on his question) when they reply to their own nomination, but not all of them. Example:

[image: not highlighted]

[image: highlighted]

In fact when I took those screenshots, I realized the candidate was highlighted when one presses "show more comments" under their nominations. Otherwise the candidate is not highlighted.

Comment: Is this really a problem?

Comment: @Integrator: It's an inconsistent behavior of the software. That is by pretty much any reasonable definition, a bug.

Comment: [Also reported on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244992/259867)

Comment: @Integrator Yes, because it would really help to be able to tell who is the candidate in each exchange at a glance.

Comment: This bug was (finally!) fixed in 2019: see [Blue background on Nominee comments only when expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220611) on Meta SE.